# Return an image from Jersey REST service to browser vs. use servlet

Tags: java, image, servlets, jersey, jax-rs

I am curious to know what is the best way to return image (*.jpg or *.gif) to the client browser:

- The first idea came up in my mind is to use the good old servlet.
- Or I can use JAX-RS (Jersy) rest service as well.

I need to create some methods for different size of images like

- thumbnails size
- small size
- normal size
- original size
- custom size

If I use servlet then I can create one servlet per image size and an extra one for custom size where I can send the desired W and H values as a URL parameters to the servlet.

If I use REST the I can create a class with methods and for the custom size I can use Path parameters.

But what about the performance?
Which solution is better and why?

Comment: you can go ahead for rest . it is good is performance and use by other source as well .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both solutions are equivalent in terms of performance. However, IMHO, JAX-RS is different from Servlet because it is declarative whereas the latter is procedural.

I would go for one endpoint only with a `@QueryParam` instead of a `@PathParam`. The size of the image is more an attribute of it than a subresource as I think you said in your question.

With this solution (that I've already implemented once) you've got only one method with annotations that make it really easy to read. For example:

```
@Path("images")
public interface ImageResource {
    enum Size {
        thumbnail, small, normal, original, custom
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces("image/jpeg")
    byte[] getImage(@PathParam("id") long id, @QueryParam("size") @DefaultValue("thumbnail") Size size, @QueryParam("width") Integer width, @QueryParam("height") Integer height);
}
```

Then if `size == Size.custom` check that both width and height are not null.